# Spring boot - Access multiple data-sources within a single request in a Multi-tenant application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

This application extracts the **subdomain** from the request url and use it as the `tenantId` to select which data-source to connect.

```
public class TenantDetectionFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private final MultiTenantManager multiTenantManager;

    public TenantDetectionFilter(MultiTenantManager multiTenantManager) {
        this.multiTenantManager = multiTenantManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            mapSubDomainToDataSource(getSubDomainFromDomain(servletRequest.getServerName()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //sending error
            return;
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    private void mapSubDomainToDataSource(String subDomain) throws Exception {
        multiTenantManager.setCurrentTenant(subDomain);
    }

    private String getSubDomainFromDomain(@NotNull String domain) {
        //logic to extract the sub-domain
    }
}
```

The class `MultiTenantManager` uses the extracted subdomain to map application to the relevant MySql database.

```
@Configuration
public class MultiTenantManager {

    public static final ThreadLocal<String> currentTenant = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private final Map<Object, Object> tenantDataSources = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private static final String DB_CONNECTOR_DRIVER = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    private AbstractRoutingDataSource multiTenantDataSource;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        multiTenantDataSource = new AbstractRoutingDataSource() {
            @Override
            protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
                return currentTenant.get();
            }
        };
        multiTenantDataSource.setTargetDataSources(tenantDataSources);
        multiTenantDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(defaultDataSource());
        multiTenantDataSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        populateTenantsProd();

        return multiTenantDataSource;
    }

    public void addTenant(String tenantId, String url, String username, String password) throws SQLException {
        DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create()
                                                 .driverClassName(DB_CONNECTOR_DRIVER)
                                                 .url(url)
                                                 .username(username)
                                                 .password(password)
                                                 .build();

        try (Connection c = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            tenantDataSources.put(tenantId, dataSource);
            multiTenantDataSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        }
    }

    public void setCurrentTenant(String tenantId) throws Exception {
        currentTenant.set(tenantId);
    }

    private DriverManagerDataSource defaultDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource defaultDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        defaultDataSource.setDriverClassName(DB_CONNECTOR_DRIVER);
        defaultDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/defaultDB");
        defaultDataSource.setUsername("username");
        defaultDataSource.setPassword("password)");
        return defaultDataSource;
    }

    private void populateTenantsProd() {
        try {
            addTenant("tenantId_1", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql_db_1", "username", "password");
            addTenant("tenantId_2", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql_db_2", "username", "password");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
}
```

Up to this point things work well. But a new requirement added to the scenario, which is to use a **MongoDB** database as well. So when a request received, Logic code should be able to use the selected (using `tenantId`) **Mysql** db for it's business logic, plus it should be able to use selected (using `tenantId`) MongoDB database for saving some meta data.

I use **Spring Data Jpa** with **Hibernate**.

1. extract sub-domain from the domain *ex: tenant_1*
2. resolve MongoDB and Mysql db names for that `tenantId`
3. Use both dbs in the business logic

Can you please explain me how to achieve this goal in Spring boot.

Comment: I assume you are going to call mysql DAO from your getSubDomainFromDomain method. 
You should have a getMongoDataSource() in your MultiTenantManager class and write daos for your mongodb. Then invoke mongodb after your mysql business logic.
you may also want to make your method transactional to make the whole thing atomic

Comment: @ArvindGangam What do you mean by "have a getMongoDataSource()". Should i declare another `AbstractRoutingDataSource` called `mongoMultiTenantDataSource` and implement `getMongoDataSource()` method to return that `mongoMultiTenantDataSource` ?

Comment: Correct, right now you have this method @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() . similarly have one more method which returns mongoDataSource. Then change your map Map<Object, Object> tenantDataSources = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); to Map<Object, List> tenantDataSources = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); and attach multiple datasources to a tenantId.
Finally, include your mongodb logic in getSubDomainFromDomain along with existing mysql logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to override the `getDb(String dbName)` to get this work.

```
public class MongoFactory extends SimpleMongoDbFactory
{

    private static final String DB_PREFIX = "prefix_";

    public MongoFactory(MongoClientURI uri)
    {
        super(uri);
    }

    public MongoFactory()
    {
        super(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost/test"));
    }

    @Override
    public MongoDatabase getDb(String dbName) throws DataAccessException
    {
        if(Objects.nonNull(currentTenant.get())){
            return super.getDb(DB_PREFIX+currentTenant.get());
        }
        return super.getDb();
    }
}
```

And in `MultiTenantManager`,

```
@Bean(name = "mongoDbFactory")
public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory()throws Exception
{
    return new MongoFactory();
}

@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(@Qualifier("mongoDbFactory") MongoDbFactory dbFactory) throws Exception
{
    return new MongoTemplate(dbFactory);
}
```